# Min-cut of mixed planar graphs

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to find the min-cut of an (s-t) planar graph, with mixed weights on it's edges meaning both positive and negative values. There are many great papers on finding the cuts, however most of these papers only mention positive graphs and nothing on mixed graphs.

Many of these papers use shortest-path algorithms such as Dijkstra's to find these cuts. So my question is, for my problem (mixed graphs) could I use the bellman-ford algorithm, which is just a shortest path algorithm for mixed graphs, and still get the same min-cut result?

Thank you

Comment: But... Ford-Fulkerson computes the maximum flow, not shortest path. How is shortest path related here?

Comment: I'm really sorry, i meant to say bellman-ford algorithm. Thank you